# Different binary outputs from js and py

Tags: javascript, python, binary, difference

I have tried turning a number into binary digits, which worked in both Python and JavaScript.
My issue is that they both return a different combination.

When I enter 585190997647163394,

JavaScript returns: 1000000111110000010000011100101001001000010000000000000000***0***0

Python returns: 1000000111110000010000011100101001001000010000000000000000***1***0

The penultimate digits in the binary combinations do not match.

---

Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
var bin = (+in).toString(2);
console.log(bin);
```

Python:

```
print(bin(int(input("int >"))))
```

Comment: JavaScript uses floating point number with double precision.  585190997647163394 is too large. `585190997647163394 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript uses floating point numbers with double precision.  585190997647163394 is too large.

```
585190997647163394 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
```

The number is rounded to     585190997647163392.

You can use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) instead.

Python has numbers with arbitrary precision. Numbers are stored as strings. Python doesn't round the number to store it.